# Defer Parsing CakePHP - How to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, cakephp

I am trying to improve my site's speed with one of the suggestions from Google's speed test, defer parsing of javascript, but I can not find any simple step by step articles on how to do this that I can comprehend. A user from Google's product forum suggested to try here.

Speed test is stating that one of files that I need to improve is:

```
websiteexample.netjs/jquery-1.4.2.js (92.5KiB)
```

I believe I found the code, but I am not sure what to add:

```
<?php //echo '<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'; ?>

<?php echo $javascript->link('jquery-1.4.2.js');?>

<?php  //echo $javascript->link('jquery.js'); ?>
```

Any ideas, suggestions or someone who can point me to the know how is greatly appreciated!

I checked out some of the other posts here on defer parsing, but the closest I could find related, the poster had his defer parsing method completely different and in a more advance technique that I think was over my experience level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is probably located here:

```
/app/webroot/js/jquery-1.4.2.js
```

Make sure you are loading the minified jQuery file and also to add the defer attribute you can try something like this:

```
<script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=function(){
        var mycode;
        mycode=document.createElement("script");
        mycode.type="text/javascript";
        mycode.src="<?php echo Router::url("/"); ?>/js/jquery-1.4.2.js";
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(mycode);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for the help!! I was so excited to test this out, and all worked perfectly. I have been trying to figure this out for a while, and though the process is simple to do, I would have never known to minimfy first or have came up with that code. Thanks again! I had tested my speed, and this has helped -Jessica

Comment: Ooo...I may have spoken too soon. Strange my score went up, all seemed fine, but something funky happen to my photo slider when viewing my homepage on Chrome and Firefox. It is frozen, and there is an odd red bar to one side of the slider and a blue bar on the the other side. Here is the script I added, and I probably altered it wrong..I will post it above to view. What did I do wrong?

Comment: I actually had to revert back to all of my original code to get my slider back to normal. Roosevelt, am I supposed to alter that code you had given me?..Like where it says "my code," lol, am  supposed to put something else there?

Comment: No. It's actually jQuery that might be throwing things off. The minified version of jQuery sometimes causes unusual errors. If you use the same <script> tag and link to your old jQuery file, your score should say that you are using the defer attribute.

Comment: Thanks for helping me Roosevelt! It was picking up that  I was using the defer attribute on those items, but there is got to be something I can do different so that it does not affect my slider. Should I try using a different minimfier? I had used a free online service that I just copied & pasted my code into to minimfy.